# Exercise 7.3.29 of Boyce's differential equation

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Contrary to its textbook concerns, this problem is Linear Algebra problem

> Suppose that $\det A=0$ and that $y$ is a solution of $A^{*}y=0$. Show that if $(b,y)=0$ for every such $y$, then $Ax = b$ has solutions.

For notation, $A^{*}$ implies conjugate transpose, and $(,)$ means inner product.

My first trial is this;

Since $(Ax-b,y) = (Ax,y)-(b,y) = (x,A^{*}y)-0 = (x,0)-0 = 0$,$Ax-b$ is orthogonal to subspace spanned by solution of $A^{*}y$. Therefore, it suffices to show that solution space of $A*y=0$ is the whole vector space.

However, I cannot prove the latter statement. Could you give me some hint for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\ker(A^*)$ (the kernel of $A^*$) denote the solution space to $A^*y = 0$.  Let $im(A)$ (the image of $A$) denote the set of $b$ for which $Ax = b$ has a solution.  If $A$ is $n \times n$, then each of these is a *subspace* of $\Bbb R^n$.

First, note that for every $y \in \ker(A^*)$ and $b \in im(A)$, we have $y \perp b$.  In particular, we may write $b = Ax$ for some $x$, whereby we deduce that $(y,b = 0)$.

Now, note that $\dim(im(A))$ is the rank of $A$, which is also the rank of $A^*$.  So, by the rank-nullity theorem, $\dim(im(A)) + \dim(\ker(A^*)) = n$.

From the previous two paragraphs, we can deduce that $im(A) = \ker(A^*)^\perp$.  That is, a vector $b$ is in $im(A)$ **if and only if** it is perpendicular to every element of $\ker(A^*)$.  So, if $(b,y) = 0$ for every element $y$ of $\ker(A^*)$, then $b$ must be in $im(A)$, which is to say that $Ax = b$ has a solution.

Comment: Thank you for clear explanation!